# Why I Cant Get Content Of My Website With C#?

Tags: c#, html

I Want Get Content Of My Website But I Cant.

Im Using This Code:

```
var myClient = new WebClient();
Stream response = myClient.OpenRead("https://profuse-blossom.glitch.me/rawtext.html/");
label3.Text = response.ToString();
```

.

But Label3 Text Is Like This;

```
<p>

vartrue

</p>

<script>
location.replace("https://profuse-blossom.glitch.me/");
</script>
```

.

**I Dont Want Source Code Of This Website.** I Want Raw Text From The Website Like This;

```
vartrue
```

can you help me? i really need this.

Comment: WebClient cannot execute the scripts inside the page, so you won't ever see script generated content. You need a headless WebBrowser, since it can render the content and return the *final product*.

Comment: If you want `WebClient` to get only `vartrue` then your site on request to `https://profuse-blossom.glitch.me/rawtext.html` return only `vartue`(now it does not, try this request in postman). If it can not - you have only option to parse content.

Comment: I see "varture" in the response though, this means you just need to parse the html text and get the body out (aka remove any tags, scripts, etc.)

Comment: @kurakura88  i cant. this link is 403 forbidden thing. if i remove script, they can access the code. i know they can look the code from `view-soruce:` but i will encrypt someways now i just want get website content

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use the [`HTMLAgilityPack`](https://html-agility-pack.net/) and using [`Nuget Link`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/)

Below is the code snippet:

```
string url = "https://www.lipsum.com/";
var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

var innerText = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```